# Can a Helm Install create a container from a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

Trying to understand the relationship between Helm and Docker containers.

Can a Helm Install create a container from a dockerfile?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold You can set it up to build a Docker image, populate your helm chart with the new container name, and deploy said chart with one command

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. A helm chart is a templated set of kubernetes manifests. There will usually by a manifest for a Pod, Deployment, or Daemonset. Any of those will have a reference to a docker image (either hard coded or a parameter). That image will usually be in a container registry like dockerhub.  You'll need to build your image using the docker file, push it to a registry, reference this image in a helm chart, then install or update helm.

Comment: It would be nice if helm would add this as standartised feature or any alternatives you can offer apart from custom scripts and bunch of different CI/CD tools (no single standard way)?